# How to seed and update column? laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just remembered from a tutorial I watched years ago, that we can set a column manually while seeding, but I can't find out the exact syntax of it.

It's like a have **UserSeeder** but I want to set the column `name` of it manually, while seeding in command line. I tried this code below but didn't work.

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder('name'=>'tempName');
```

Somebody knows how to do it?

Comment: What I understand is that you need to specify column/column-value in your `seeder` file, not in `php artisan db:seed` command

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume that the seeder will seed users into the database.

Run the following artisan command :

```
php artisan make:seeder UserSeeder
```

This artisan command will generate a file called `UserSeeder.php` inside of your `database/seeders` folder.

Inside the `run()` function of the seeder class write your logic, for example:

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;   


public function run()
        {
            DB::table('users')->insert([
                'name' => 'admin',
                'email' => 'admin@somesite.com',
                'password' => Hash::make('myuserpassword'),
            ]);
        }
```

Then, go to `database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php` and call that seeder:

```
 public function run()
    {
        $this->call([UserSeeder::class]);
    }
```

Lastly, Don't forget to run the seeders:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

For more information check the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding